# How to use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS in one query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, exists

Table1

```
Id Name  DemoID
1  a      33
2  b      44
3  c      33
4  d      33
5  e      44
```

Table2

```
Id DemoID IsTrue
11  33     1  
12  44     1
```

Table3

```
Id Table1_ID
11  1
```

Now we can find which DemoID is present in Table2 using below query -

```
SELECT Table1.Id FROM Table1 as Table1
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT * FROM Table2 as Table2
   WHERE Table1.DemoID  = Table2.DemoID AND Table2.IsTrue= 1
)
```

result - 1,2,3,4,5

But I also want to check into 3rd table whether those records are EXISTS OR NOT. using one more condition NOT EXISTS in same query ?

for example `Table3` has `Table1_ID` column value only 1 now new NOT exist query should give me result `2,3,4,5`

I tried like -

```
SELECT Table1.Id FROM Table1 as Table1
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
       SELECT * FROM Table2 as Table2
       WHERE Table1.DemoID  = Table2.DemoID AND Table2.IsTrue= 1
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table3)
```

but it is giving me no records. it should give me remaining records those are 2,3,4,5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The condition:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table3)
```

...is always false if there are any rows in Table3, so your query returns no rows.

You need to add a predicate to show how Table3 rows are qualified, as shown in bold below:

```
SELECT Table1.Id
FROM Table1 AS Table1
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM Table2 AS Table2
        WHERE
            Table1.DemoID  = Table2.DemoID 
            AND Table2.IsTrue= 1
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Table3
        WHERE
            Table3.Table1_ID = Table1.Id -- New
    );
```

Demo: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=2c1d8cdf1a2a6640cbd2940a6aa10973)